# Why can't we create an Anonymous Static Nested class in JAVA?

Tags: java, class, static, nested, anonymous

I've been researching and trying to understand the implications of this declaration but I don't seem to find a definite answer.

Can someone educate me, please?

Comment: An unsatisfying answer would be [because the specification says so](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se11/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.9.5). Possibly the authors did not want to support this combination. Would there be any benefit to it?

Comment: @dratenik that's a very good question, and honestly I don't know the answer to it. It's just one of those things that keeps bugging me because I can't quite understand it.

Comment: One plausible (non-)answer is that *it doesn't make sense*. If a thing is static, then it's a member of a class/type; and if it's a member, it has an identifier, making it not anonymous. But beyond that, it gets absurd/mysterious. The JLS link posted by @dratenik is useful and relevant indeed, giving the authoritative answer, but I think that's pretty much the most meaningless part of the JLS, it raises so many questions. For one, I can't see why the body of an (non-static) anonymous class declared in a static method such as `main` can't access the enclosing class's instance members.